# basic python query. NameError in __init__ method

Tags: python, oop, nameerror

NameError: name 'the_shape' is not defined

I get the following error when I try to import my KMeans module containing the class named KMeansClass. The KMeans.py module has the following structure:

```
import numpy as np 
import scipy
class KMeansClass:
    #takes in an npArray like object
    def __init__(self,dataset,the_shape=5):
        self.dataset=dataset
        self.mu = np.empty(shape=the_shape)
```

and in ipython when I try 
 import KMeans

I get the `NameError: name 'the_shape' is not defined`

I am really new to python OOP and don't know why this is happening as all I'm doing is passing arguments to init and assigning those arguments to instance variables.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Full Traceback:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-44169aae5584> in <module>()
----> 1 import kmeans

/Users/path to file/kmeans.py in <module>()
      1 import numpy as np
      2 import scipy
----> 3 class KMeansClass:
      4         #takes in an npArray like object
      5         def __init__(self,dataset,the_shape=5):

/Users/path_to_file/kmeans.py in KMeansClass()
      5         def __init__(self,dataset,the_shape=5):
      6                 self.dataset=dataset
----> 7         self.mu = np.empty(shape=the_shape)
      8 
      9 

NameError: name 'the_shape' is not defined
```

Comment: The code you've shown seems fine. Can you edit to include a full traceback of your exception? It seems like it must be coming from some other code.

Comment: Note the indentation: looks like you are mixing tabs and spaces for indentation. Don't do that; better to stick to *just* spaces (configure your editor to replace tabs with spaces for indentation).

Comment: I added the traceback. Still unable to figure it out.

Comment: To be certain, run your code with `python -tt scriptname.py`.

Comment: ah I see. It fixed my problem. It was the indentation problem as you suggested. Thanks for your help,this error really stumped me because usually when I mix tabs with spaces I get an IndentationError and then I go back and fix it. But this was a first thanks! :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about tab/space issues with the OPs code and not the code posted here

Comment: Don't do this. Besides some IDE would help you avoid this in the first place, I use Spyder myself https://pypi.python.org/pypi/spyder